# Wildfly Swarm Uber Jar failing cause of missing Dependancy that the application code base doesnt use

Tags: java, wildfly-swarm

**Background:** 
Currently we run our Java EE applications off monolith wildfly servers. I have been working with the developers to get the applications ready to move to microservices. Because of an article by James Falkner over at developers dot redhat, I decided to go with creating a hollow jar using wildfly-swarm so the creation and deployment of new containers would be super fast. I also figured that moving from wildfly to wildfly swarm would be easier than moving to springboot.

**The Problem:** 
After more work than i expected i did get an Uber jar to build, figuring once i had that i could muck about and get the hollow jar working. The problem comes when running the jar i keep getting the same error:

```
    ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by: 
    org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:         
    org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException:         
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-spring
```

I talked to the developers and their code doesn’t use the resteasy-spring module, so i figure its something that wildfly-swarm is asking for but after trying all the things i could find on google about this, none worked.

**My Question:**
If anyone has any ideas to fix this Error, I will try anything you send me, even if it is redoing some of the things I have already tried. i figure if you mention it, you got it working for you and maybe i missed something when trying to do it off the google results.

EDIT: Adding dependencies from pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Testing libraries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datasources</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-multipart</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And the dependencyManagement section:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Self dependencies removed -->

        <!-- company specific dependencies removed  -->

        <!-- APIs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MISC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graylog2.log4j2</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j2-gelf</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ActiveMQ/JMS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${activemq.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ (for AOP) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Kryo (Serialization library) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.esotericsoftware</groupId>
            <artifactId>kryo</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>${redis.jedis.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-fileupload.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf-itext5</artifactId>
            <version>${flying-saucer-itextpdf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
            <version>${docx4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fi.solita.clamav</groupId>
            <artifactId>clamav-client</artifactId>
            <version>${clamv.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxbcore.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.jaxb-namespaceprefixmapper-interfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>JAXBNamespacePrefixMapper</artifactId>
            <version>${namespaceprefixmapper.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-redis.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly-swarm}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

This is what my jboss-deployment-structure.xml looks like. Still having issues:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
       <exclude-subsystems>
           <subsystem name="resteasy"/>
       </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <!-- Added in attempt to get rid of resteasy issue -->
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-spring"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.jackson-provider"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-atom-provider"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jettison-provider"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-yaml-provider"/>
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: Can you share what dependencies are in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: @Ken added the dependencies. Anything look to be missing or set up wrong?

Comment: The problem is that the `resteasy-spring` module is not included in the deployment, which is why classes from that module can't be found.

You need to add a dependency on that module using a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file in your WAR

Comment: @Ken Still getting the issue. added my jboss-deployment-structure.xml file to see if you have any insights, such as I did it totally wrong.

Comment: I don't think you want any exclusions, but rather an inclusion of "resteasy-spring" module

Comment: @bigw8 have you tried with removing `jaxrs` swarm fraction? I have a project that uses Spring MVC and when moving it from Wildfly to Wildfly Swarm I got `ModuleNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-spring` error when `jaxrs` fraction was included in the project. NOTE: the project uses only spring for REST, so I could afford to not include `jaxrs` fraction.